# Optimizing the Generic List WHERE

Tags: c#, lambda, generic-list

The statement below takes around 6 seconds to produce the output when the SecurityInfoMasterList has around 11,000 items and listClassiNode has around 750 items.

Is there any other way of doing this to achieve the same result but with better performance?

```
List<SecurityInfo> listSecurityInfo = SecurityInfoMasterList.Where(c => 
    listClassiNode.Any(d => 
        c.SX == d.Exch && c.Instrument == d.Instrument)).ToList();
```

I have been trying to use for loop but didnt see much improvement.

Updated:

listClassiNode is a List

```
[Serializable]
     public class SecurityInfo
    {
    public string SecurityID { get; set; }
    public int SecurityTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string SecurityName { get; set; }
    public int DB { get; set; }
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public long GICS { get; set; }
    public string ICB { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string IndustryGroup { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    public string Instrument { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string SX { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
  }



[Serializable()]
    public class ClassificationNode
    {
        public string Exch { get; set; }
        public string Instrument { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
    }
```

Alan

Comment: can you give more info about the object, what is SX, Exch, Intrument property?

Comment: SX, Exch and Instrument are type of string. SecurityInfo object consists of other properties as well.

Comment: thanks, i  updated the code in my answer with your class and test scenario to play :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert your `listClassiNode` into some kind of `HashSet`, so that lookups are `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>(
    listClassiNode.Select(t => 
        string.Format("{0}_{1}", t.Exch, t.Instrument)).Distinct());

List<SecurityInfo> listSecurityInfo = SecurityInfoMasterList.Where(c => 
    hash.Contains(string.Format("{0}_{1}", c.SX, c.Instrument))
        .ToList();
```

The above is a little clumsy, with the `string.Format` creating a concatenated key to use for the HashSet. Hopefully, the nature of your data is such that it won't be a problem. Anyway, you get the idea, I hope.

Comment: it works like a charm Blorgbead. It takes less than a second now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One obvious optimisation is to avoid the call to `Distinct`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx *If collection contains duplicates, the set will contain one of each unique element. No exception will be thrown. Therefore, the size of the resulting set is not identical to the size of collection.*

Answer (score 3):

you can try using Parallel see if it helps

```
List<SecurityInfo> listSecurityInfo = SecurityInfoMasterList.AsParallel.Where(c => 
    listClassiNode.Any(d => 
        c.SX == d.Exch && c.Instrument == d.Instrument)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

using your class

this take about 4 to 5 seconds to run in DEBUG mode

12,000 x 12,000 instead of 11,000 x 750

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listSecurityInfo = new List<SecurityInfo>();
            var listClassiNode = new List<ClassiNode>();

            initList(listSecurityInfo, listClassiNode);

            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var matched = listSecurityInfo.Where(c => listClassiNode.Any(d =>  c.SX == d.Exch && c.Instrument == d.Instrument)).ToList();
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms matched: " +matched.Count());
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void initList(List<SecurityInfo> listSecurityInfo, List<ClassiNode> listClassiNode)
        {
            var rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 12000; ++i)
            {
                listSecurityInfo.Add(new SecurityInfo()
                {
                    SX = new string(Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(40, 125)), 4000),
                    Instrument = new string(Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(40, 125)), 4000)
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 12000; ++i)
            {
                listClassiNode.Add(new ClassiNode()
                {
                    Exch = new string(Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(40, 125)), 4000),
                    Instrument = new string(Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(40, 125)), 4000)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```